# Como fazer a media individual de cada elemento em uma matriz

Tags: python, numpy

Olá, eu tenho a seguinte matriz:

```
matriz = np.array([
    [5, 5, 5],
    [5, 5, 5],
    [10, 10, 10]
])
```

e preciso do resultado com um array de suas respectivas medias, dessa forma:

`[6.66, 6.66, 6.66]`

Grato

Comment: O que você já fez? ;)

Comment: Por enquanto só procurando na documentação do numpy, eu gostaria de resolver essa situação com apenas uma função do numpy.

Comment: [`numpy.average`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) e [`numpy.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)ajuda? Parece ser o que procura

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando a função `numpy.average` você consegue calcular a média dos valores de um `array` para um determinado eixo.
Ex:

```
matriz = np.array([
    [5, 5, 5],
    [5, 5, 5],
    [10, 10, 10]
])

#media para o eixo Y
media = np.average(matriz, axis=0)
```

Saída da variável `media`:

```
[6.66666667 6.66666667 6.66666667]
```

Na [documentação](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) você pode ver melhor sobre os parâmetros.